# Keeping part of a path in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, split

I'm new to python and I'm trying to keep part of the following:
'/this/is/my/path'
and I would like to keep this:
'/my/path'

My problem is that the path is dynamic and the length is not the same all the times. And practically I would like to 'delete' the first two parts.

If I use this:
os.getcwd().split("/")[2:5] 
my problem is that is not dynamic and also it converts it into a list that I do not want.
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the first folder in a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724275/removing-the-first-folder-in-a-path)

Comment: `os.path.sep.join(os.getcwd().split(os.path.sep)[2:])` should get you pretty far, though.