# How to loop over a folder, and recreate them in another folder with same structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, directory-structure, os.path

I want to process a folder and blur the images and recreate them in another folder while preserving the structure.

My source folder has the following structure

```
Data/
   test1/
      test2/
         6.png
      4.png
      5.jpeg
   1.jpg/
   2.jpg
   3.jpeg
```

I wanted to blur all these images and save them in another folder

```
src = 'C:\Users\shakhansho\Downloads\Data' #folder with images
dst = 'C:\Users\shakhansho\Downloads\Output' #folder for output
```

let's say I have a function which takes a path to image and then applies blurring and then saves it in the same directory `blur(path_to_img)`

How can I loop over the `src` files, blur and then save in `dst` folder with preserving the structure.I would like the `dst` folder contain the same folder name and image names but blurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) (or `glob.iglob`) for this. It can recursively find all files under a directory. Then, we can simply open the images in some way, transform them, find the output file and folder, optionally create that folder, and write out transformed images. The code contains comments to elaborate these steps slightly.

```
import glob
import os

# Recursively find all files under Data/
for filepath in glob.iglob("Data/**/*.*", recursive=True):
    # Ignore non images
    if not filepath.endswith((".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg")):
        continue

    # Open your image and perform your transformation
    # to get the blurred image
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        image = f.read()
        blurred = transform(image)
    
    # Get the output file and folder path
    output_filepath = filepath.replace("Data", "Output")
    output_dir = os.path.dirname(output_filepath)
    # Ensure the folder exists
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Write your blurred output files
    with open(output_filepath, "w") as f:
        f.write(blurred)
```

I recreated your file structure, and my program was able to re-create the exact file structure, but under `Output` instead.

Comment: Just a note that `os.path` has a modern alternative `pathlib`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It works when `src` and `dst` are similar. That's where you used `output_filepath = filepath.replace("Data", "Output")`. However, if output path is different from input path, the code doesn't work ( For examples, I changed the output path to `C:\Users\shakhansho\Downloads\archive\Output'` and its not working

Comment: You should be able to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/26724369/17936326 to remove "Data" from the path using `pathlib`, and then you can merge that with `C:\Users\shakhansho\Downloads\archive\Output` to get the final output path.